# RuntimeException: "Unable to destroy activity"; "Service not registered"

Tags: android, service

I've looked at the other posts on this issue and can't see what I'm doing wrong. When I click the "back" button on the tablet, I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {...TestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ...TestActivity@1035a3d1
```

The line that causes the error is `unbindService()` here:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy( ) {
        super.onDestroy( );  // does putting this line first fix the "can't destroy activity; service is not registered" crash? No.
        if( serviceBound ) {
            getApplicationContext().unbindService( this ); // ('this' is ServiceConnection implementation)
            serviceBound = false;
        } else {
            if( DEBUG ) Log.d( TAG, "onDestroy() found that ThermocoupleService was not bound" );
        }
        onStopDisposables.clear();  // because apparently onStop() isn't always called
    }
```

The `IllegalArgumentException` appears to refer to `this`, which is the Activity I'm trying to unbind. It implements the `ServiceConnection` interface.

The Service is bound in `onStart()` like so:

```
bindThermoServiceIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ThermocoupleService.class );
if( !( serviceBound = bindService( bindThermoServiceIntent, /*ServiceConnection interface*/ this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE ) ) ) 
    throw new RuntimeException( TAG + ": bindService() call in onStart() failed" );
serviceComponentName = getApplicationContext().startService( bindThermoServiceIntent );  // bind to it AND start it
if( DEBUG ) Log.d( TAG, "Service running with ComponentName " + serviceComponentName.toShortString() );
```

Other than this problem, the Activity and Service seem to work fine. The Service uses `startForeground()` to keep itself running.

Comment: `// ('this' is ServiceConnection implementation)` -- since `ServiceConnection` does not have an `onDestroy()` method that you can override, this code should not compile, let alone run. `this` is presumably an activity.

Comment: `public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServiceConnection` contains implementations of the `onServiceConnected()` and `onServiceDisconnected` methods of the `ServiceConnection` interface. I have used this in other apps without problems.

Comment: IMHO, an activity should not be implementing `ServiceConnection`, as that can cause problems with configuration changes. IMHO, you should put your `ServiceConnection` in a `ViewModel` or retained fragment. With respect to the crash, apparently Android does not think that you have a valid `ServiceConnection`. You are binding in `onStart()` and are trying to unbind in `onDestroy()`, and those are not a matching pair of lifecycle methods. Either bind in `onCreate()` or unbind in `onStop()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was unbinding in `onDestroy()` because I have read that `onStop()` is not guaranteed to be called when an Activity is suspended. Maybe try doing it in both? (with the boolean flag to control the second try)

Comment: I do not know what "suspended" means in this context. Please stick with the lifecycle pairs. Either use `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` **or** use `onStart()` and `onStop()`. Mixing those up can lead to double-initialization or double-termination problems.